# Windows update: Download percentage not shown anymore

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I am working on Windows 8.1. Some time ago, I reserved the update for Windows 10. However, in the meantime, I have changed my mind and want to take some time before switching.

I disabled the Windows 10 Update by hiding it and uninstalled the KB3035583 update.

Now whenever I install updates (e.g. definition files for Windows Defender), instead of the normal progress bar, it only shows *Downloading Windows 10*. At first, I was afraid this was true, but it is not. Windows *is* downloading my selected updates, but I can just not see any progress.

How can I get the progress bar back?

Comment: Just so you know, you need to actually press keys to do the windows 10 update. You can unhide that specific update without any problems.

Comment: That's absolutely true. The thing is: If the update is not hidden, it is always suggested and automatically selected, so you must always uncheck it before installing other updates. That's not quite what I want.

Comment: I see. Can't tell you for sure if installing that update is the actual upgrade, or just an update to the icon in the system tray. I think its just an icon in the system tray though.

Comment: KB3035583 is the GWX (Get Windows 10) program, the one that shows the icon in the system tray. With that, you can trigger the actual download of Windows 10, and after that, you can start the update. I accidentally started the *download* of Windows 10 (because it was preselected) and then stopped it. Since then, I uninstalled KB3035583, deleted the GWX folder in system32 and disabled KB3035583 to prevent re-installation.

Comment: Ah, so it is the icon. You can safely install that update, as its only the icon.

Comment: Yes, I know it is the icon. But I don't want it for now, that's why I uninstalled and disabled it. I could also just have hidden the icon, but I chose to do the complete uninstall, in order to check whether this solves my problem with the progress bar. After all, if all GWX are deleted, there is no reason, why Windows Update should show that Windows 10 message instead of the normal progress bar. And GWX is not needed anyway, as since the release, Windows Update shows Windows 10 availability automatically.